# Android: Google Place API queryAutoComplete delivers ZERO_RESULTS on API 17 - API 19

Tags: android, google-places-api, nativescript

The following request works fine in web and in android API 17+:

Search string: `Bruņinieku ie`

Search url: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=Bruņinieku%20ie&key=xxx](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=Bru%C5%86inieku%20ie&key=xxx)

Search results:

```
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Bruņinieku iela, Rīga, Latvija",
         "id" : "6904e5bf90ff4e34b179aba2e28643efc9007017",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 13,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
    ...
```

Now, if I add another letter at the end, the request still works fine in web and in android API 21+, but not in API 17 - API 19:

Search string: `Bruņinieku iel`

Search url: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=Bruņinieku%20iel&key=xxx](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=Bru%C5%86inieku%20iel&key=xxx)

Search results (Web and API 21+):

```
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Bruņinieku iela, Rīga, Latvija",
         "id" : "6904e5bf90ff4e34b179aba2e28643efc9007017",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 15,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
    ...
```

Search results (API 17 - API 19):

```
{
    "predictions": [],
    "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

WHY?! Makes absolutely no sense! At first I thought it might be the location or radius or language, so removed those - still the same problem. This shouldn't happen, but it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greeeeat, half day wasted. As it turns out, the old APIs do not convert unknown symbols, such as `ņ` to utf-8 automatically. You have to do it yourself with `encodeURIComponent(search_string)` which results in url:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=Bru%C5%86inieku%20iel&key=xxx